# res.locals value getting changed when simultaneous users access the site

Tags: node.js, express

I am working a nodejs express website. It is actually a frontend implementation for Oracle commerce(ATG). Nodejs Express communicate with ATG through rest APIs.

I am not storing any sessions in nodejs. Nodejs just stands as a intermediate between user and ATG. So all communications from browser is made to ATG server using cookie pass through by nodejs(Passing the cookie from browser to REST API). This is to ensure that nodejs does not have to store any session variables.

Issue:
I am using res.locals to store global information like login status, logged in user details, header cart summary. Now when multiple users access the site, the usernames or cart gets interchanged. ie If Mike has logged in, after some time Mike will see cart items of some other user.

According to my understanding res.locals will not change for a particular request response life cycle. But the value is getting changed in between.

Any leads will be helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some code? The smallest executable block of code that reproduces your issue will give you the best chances of getting an answer ;)

Comment: if you maintain session only you can maintain state of the user in client app, you need to maintain